Relationship between LWE, SIS, and ISIS
Suppose I have a short-secret LWE instance $As+e=b\mod q$. If I treat this as a single matrix, it becomes an ISIS problem:
$$ \begin{pmatrix} I &A\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} e \\ s\end{pmatrix}=b\mod q$$
Any short solution to this problem solves my LWE problem. If my ISIS solver expects uniformly random matrix, I can multiply both sides on the left by a random invertible matrix $B$. Thus LWE with parameters $(n,m)$ and secret and error bounded by norm $\beta$ can be reduced to ISIS$_{m,n+m,\beta}$.
Conversely, given an ISIS problem $As=t\mod q$, I can row-reduce $A$ to bring it to the same form as above: $UA = (I | A')$ for some $U$; then I give $A',Ut\mod q$ to my LWE oracle and it returns $(s,e)$ such that
$$A's+e=Ut\mod q$$
And so $(e,s)$ solves my ISIS problem: ISIS$_{m,n,\beta}$ reduces to LWE$_{m,n-m,\beta}$.
Going further, ISIS and SIS are equivalent (sort of): Given an ISIS problem $(A,t,\beta)$, pick a random short value $y\in\mathbb{Z}_q$ then give $[A|-y^{-1}t]$ to an SIS solver and it will return $(s,\beta)$ such that $As=\beta y^{-1}t\mod q$. Waving my hands a bit, probably if $y$ is chosen randomly there will eventually be some collision where $\beta=y$ and one obtains $As=t\mod q$.
Conversely, given an SIS problem $(A,\beta)$, let $A=[A'|a]$ where $a$ is the last column of $A$, then iterate through random short $y$ and give $(A',-y^{-1}a)$ to the ISIS solver. It will give you some short $s$ such that $A's=-y^{-1}a\mod q$, so $(s,y)$ is an SIS solution.
This all seems completely reasonable to me. Except, the literature treats these problems very differently! No one says Kyber is based on the hardness of Module-SIS.
The main difference seems to be paramater regimes: LWE is often thought of as "injective", where $(s,e)\mapsto As+e$ is likely an injective function. One can take $A$ to be a square matrix, so that following the above reductions, the corresponding ISIS and SIS problems will involve matrices only twice as wide as they are tall, while typical descriptions of SIS use (number of columns)=$O($(number of rows)$\log q)$. With the smaller regime, SIS and ISIS might have no solutions at all for certain $\beta$, and the above reductions might fail (though I think one can argue that if a solution exists for one, there is some value of $y$ that will make the reduction produce that solution). With the larger regime, counting arguments say that the range of $As$ should be surjective.
Yet, the above reductions imply that ISIS and SIS should still be hard with (number of columns) = 2(number of rows).
Finally, it's easy to show (as long as LWE stays injective) that wider secret and error distributions are harder for LWE (just add your own error before passing to the oracle). The situation for surjective SIS seems to be the opposite: if you have an oracle for a smaller norm bound, just call that and return the answer (as long as $A\mapsto As$ is still surjective in the smaller regime).
The trick seems to be that LWE is actually a promise problem: given $(A,b)$, you're typically promised that a solution exists (or you need to decide this, which is just as hard). But in the surjective parameter regime for SIS/ISIS, there is no promise. The above reduction would fail because if you choose a norm bound so small that there are no solutions, a smaller-norm-SIS oracle is useless.
Anyway, this is more of a rant than a question. Overall, my question is: is this right? Do I have the right perspective and intuition on these two problems? And is there a more authoritative resource that spells out these differences, so that when I see a paper that assumes, e.g., MSIS, I can tell whether they mean the surjective regime or the injective regime?

Typically, how this is described is that SIS and LWE are “dual” to each other. See for example page 10 of “A Decade of Lattice Cryptography”. It cites Micciancio’s Invited 2010 PKC talk “Duality in Lattice Cryptography” (see around page 16 - SIS is described as “Ajtai’s hash function”). You can also see Micciancio’s lecture notes (section 3). Not writing an answer though as I haven’t worked with this stuff myself.

Those are very helpful, though they don't quite resolve my dissatisfaction. Papers referencing SIS hardness assumptions don't typically specify whether they mean in the injective or surjective regime -- should they, or should a reader be able to pick this up easily from context?

Generally, SIS is used to refer to the surjective regime, where one cannot build PKE, but can still build signatures. So the distinction is akin to minicrypt/cryptomania.

I agree that there is redundancy in the definitions of lattice problems. This has to do with how they were historically defined.
If someone asked me how to redefine everything, I would say just define the ISIS problem, and make it analogous to how the knapsack (i.e. subset sum) problem was defined in the 80's.  So we would have "low-density" ISIS, which is injective, and "high density" ISIS, which is surjective. You would also have the decision version, which only makes sense in the injective regime since it's vacuously hard in the other one. And you would have the homogeneous version, which only makes sense in the surjective regime since it's vacuously hard in the other one. That's it.
The LWE problem was originally defined where the secret was uniform and the errors came from a small distribution.  Then it was shown that the secret can come from the same small distribution as the error and the problem is just as hard. This means that the LWE problem, with a fixed number of samples, is exactly the injective ISIS problem. If you wanted, you could also define search-LWE in the surjective regime, and then it becomes the surjective ISIS problem. So there is no reason to have both ISIS and LWE -- if you allow their surjective and injective versions, then they are the same problem. For convention, though, when people say LWE, they mean the injective version of ISIS (with possibly an arbitrary number of samples / arbitrary number of rows in ISIS).
The SIS problem is the homogeneous version of ISIS, and only makes sense in the surjective regime, since it's vacuously hard in the other one.  There is a reduction SIS < ISIS (and sometimes ISIS < SIS), but the size of the solutions grow or the time of the reduction depends on the size of the solution space per coefficient. In practice, though, the homogeneous and non-homogeneous version of ISIS are (strongly) believed to be equally hard.
So, to summarize, we have low and high-density ISIS and as convention,
SIS = homogeneous version of surjective ISIS
(decision) LWE = (decision) injective ISIS
When people say "SIS" and "LWE", it's clear what they mean.  When they talk about ISIS, then they should specify the parameter regime (though perhaps there is some tilt towards the meaning that ISIS = high-density ISIS).

Thanks, and it was actually your paper "Lattice-based Zero-Knowledge Proofs and Applications: Shorter, Simpler, and More General" that prompted my question: Lemma 3.1 uses the hardness of MSIS, which I should take to mean "high-density MSIS". I was wondering whether the same results hold for LWE (i.e., low-density MSIS) and whether that's implied by Lemma 3.1 or needs a new (but identical) proof

And breaking the rules to ask a follow-up in the comments: that same lemma states that if MSIS is hard, then the secrets $s_1$ and $s_2$ such that $A_1s_1+A_2s_2=t$ are unique. But if it's high-density MSIS, that's only true computationally? I.e., a more accurate phrasing would be something like "If MSIS is hard, any poly-time extractor will produce the same $s_1$ and $s_2$"

So for MSIS, there is only the high-density version -- it makes no sense in the low-density regime (see what I said about SIS towards the end of my answer).  With a different parametrization, you could have commitment schemes be binding based on LWE, but this would be less efficient because the hiding property would be based on an even easier version of LWE (you can look at the discussion in Section 5.3 of https://eprint.iacr.org/2024/1287.pdf where I explain why basing signatures purely on LWE is less efficient).  Also, Ajtai commitments, which are compressing, cannot be based on LWE.

And yes, you're right about the interpretation of "unique" in that Lemma.

Ah, that hits almost exactly my confusion! But still: that discussion focuses on the efficiency of rejection sampling and the size of $\beta$ - but LWE allows you to choose $n=O(m)$ (like Dilithium) whereas SIS requires $n=O(m\log q)$ (if $n$ is the space of the secret). That seems like it could overcome the other efficiency losses. And what stops me from an Ajtai-like commitment of Commit$(s_1)=A_1s_1+e_1+A_2s_2+e_2$? In the injective regime it's information-theoretically hiding and computationally binding, no?

SIS does not require $n=O(m\log{q})$. You can have $n=2m$ when you set $\beta\approx\sqrt{q}$. What that section implies is that if you give me a signature scheme based purely on LWE (resp. SIS), then I can increase (resp. decrease) $\beta$ to make it more secure. Once it's more secure, I can adjust $n,m$ down to make it more efficient and bring the security down to what it originally was.

Yes, you could have an Ajtai-like commitment be based on injective ISIS as you said (except you need to multiply your $e_2$ by some matrix $A_3$, otherwise one can break binding by switching things between $e_1$ and $e_2$).  I think my sentence about Ajtai commitments a few comments up was ambiguous. What I meat to say is that ``If Ajtai commitments are compressing, then they cannot be based on LWE''
